# Can I allow users to be logged in to symfony using a link with a secret key?

Tags: symfony

I'd like to e-mail all my users a link to a symfony site that I am writing, and have it so that when they follow that link they are logged in to the site (probably with a special role, like IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED), and redirected to a certain page. How can I do this?

So the link would be something like:

```
http://example.com/?key=[some sort secret key with their account encoded in it]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this](http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-devs/browse_thread/thread/b51f2dd32c2bf2ce#msg_537f3cbb7be5a6aa) message and [this](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L118) code, I wrote a controller that gets the user from the database, verifies the secret key, then fakes a login token as follows:

```
$providerKey = 'secured_area'; // Name of firewall from security.yml - not sure this is correct.
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, array('AUTO_LOGIN'));

$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

(you need this at the top of your file)

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
```

It seems to work, and the user has a role of `AUTO_LOGIN` so I can easily restrict them from accessing more sensitive stuff until they have logged in with a username and password as normal.

Answer (score 2):

i'd do something like this: generate the key with a hash function over the username. 
Then send them a link to `http://example.com/?user=`username`&hash=`the-hash-result.

In the action that will recieve this url you can get the request parameter `username` and `hash`, apply the same hash funcion to the username you recived and compare the result to the hash key in the request parameters.

If match, just set the appropiate credentials to the user and log him in

Lets see some code, in your authentication class you should have a function to authenticate a user with the `$user` and `$password` parameters. Here or extending this class you can define a funciton like this:

```
function authenticate($user,$hash-key){
    if(hashFunction($user) == $hash-key){
        $user->setAuthFunction(true);//sort of
    }
}
```

Hope it helped you!

Comment: I strongly recommend using a unique hash for every user. Otherwise it can be way too easy to figure out the hash (by trying 20 most popular algos) and eventually break into the system.

Comment: FOSUserBundle stores a unique salt in the database with the rest of the user's information... you could use an approach like this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been clearer. I realise I can use a hash function, either of the user's username, or of their unique ID in the database. The question is how do I integrate with the Symfony framework's authentication system.

Comment: @gilden You need to append a (preferably longish) secret key string to the username before you hash it. That way you would have to brute-force guess the secret key before you could generate your own hashes and break into the other people's accounts. But that part is easy. The question is how do I integrate such a system into Symfony's user account system.

Comment: Is absolutley necessary to implement it inside the authentication system? if so, maybe you can extend the class you use to authenticate normally your users and add this behaviour as a function, and in action, just call that function

Comment: @AndreuHeineken I suppose it's not _absolutely_ necessary that I implement in in the authentication system, but it would be really stupid if I didn't - I'd need to handle users who have logged in with username & password separately in lots of places. I'm hoping to evolve what I am currently building over time into a major system, and I don't want hacks like that put in at this early stage.

Comment: then you can overload the function you use to authenticate the users with `$user` and `$pwd` parameters, with `$user` and `$hash-key` parameters instead, in the same class or extending it. Then you can call one or the other depending on your needs in each case.

Answer (score 1):

Not so easy to implement I can tell you but you got to take a look to the UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener::attemptAuthentication method...
Make your own service to atteptAuthentication automaticaly.